# ¿Por qué Sudo SSH... sigue solicitando la contraseña de la clave privada pero sin Sudo no la pide?

Tags: linux, ssh

Cuando guardas la contraseña de la clave privada en el repositorio  `~/.ssh/` es posible hacer ingreso a SSH con el comando `ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/key.pem ..."` y no se solicita contraseña ( porque ya está guardada) lo extraño es que si hago lo mismo pero con SUDO, `sudo ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/clave.pem ..."` vuelve a solicitar la contraseña de la clave.

Incluso probe cambiando el archivo clave.pem a `/root/.ssh/clave.pem` y luego aplicando `ssh-ssh-add /root/.ssh/clave.pem`pero nada: `sudo ssh -i /root/.ssh/clave.pem..` sigue pidiendo la contraseña de la clave privada.

Obviamente estoy haciendo algo mal. ¿Cómo hacer esto en forma correcta?

**Nota**: Para mi caso es necesario aplicar SUDO

Comment: de casualidad te equivocaste al escribir `ssh-add /root/.ssh/nextnode.pem` cuando en realidad querías escribir `ssh-add /root/.ssh/clave.pem`?

Comment: @Cuauhtli Si es un error al escribir aquí, para el ejemplo es clave.pem ( ya lo corregi)

Answer (score 0):

Hola estás haciendo mal el uso del `sudo`, el `sudo` tienes que ejecutarlo una vez te conectas por ssh, no antes, porque `sudo` es un programa que sirve para ejecutar otro programa con permisos root, eso quiere decir que `sudo ssh` hace que se ejecute el programa `sudo` de tu máquina y ejecute el programa ssh con permisos root local, lo cual no es lo que quieres, tu quieres que lo que ejecutes dentro del Shell remoto se ejecute como root.

Ahora si con el problema en específico, a pesar del mal uso del sudo, no termino de entender si con contraseña te refieres al passphrase o a que el host remoto te pide contraseña.

Asumiré que es la passphrase así, que la respuesta sería que el root no ha guardado la frase en su keychain, para eso tienes que ejecutar `ssh-add` con el usuario correspondiente(en este caso, si deseas que sea root, puedes hacerlo con `sudo`)

```
sudo ssh-add /path/to/pemfile.pem
```

Al ejecutar te pedirá la passphrase una sola vez, y ya nunca más.

Comment: por su pregunta anterior creo que se refiere al passphrase.

Comment: @Cuauhtli Gracias por tu respuesta, No estoy haciendo mal uso de sudo. Lo que estoy exponiendo es solo una parte de un script más grande. cuando lo llamo tengo que llamarlo con Sudo por que el resto del script necesita permisos de root para ejecutarse. Por otro lado por contraseña si me refiero al passphrase o "Frase de contraseña" en español.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces solucionaste el problema? para encontrar el error más rápido, prueba todo con usuario root `su root`, y luego que funcione así, ya lo haces con `sudo`. Que te aparece al ejecutar `ssh-add -L` como root?

Comment: @EduardoMunizaga entonces sal del `sudo` por el ssh. Es inutil hacer ssh con sudo. O bien lo haces como `root` o sin `sudo`. Quizás mejor hacer otra pregunta explicando tu script con mas detalle porque hay algo muy raro aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Como comentario para aquellos que vengan de preguntarse cómo guardar el passphrase de una llave privada. Primero hay que exportar las variables de ambiente que saca `ssh-agent` y cargarlas en nuestro ambiente, para eso nos valemos de

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

o

```
ssh-agent $(getent passwd $LOGNAME | cut -d: -f7)
```

Donde el comando `getent passwd $LOGNAME | cut -d: -f7` te da la ruta de la shell del tu usuario.

Y, una vez cargadas las variables, ya podemos proceder a añadir las *passphrases* de las llaves privadas al agente de autenticación con `ssh-add /ruta/de/la/llave`

Por ejemplo, tengo tres llaves privadas.

```
$ ls -l
total 12
-rw------- 1 root root 1766 Jul 29 02:53 llave_prueba
-rw------- 1 root root 1766 Jul 29 02:55 llave_prueba2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  402 Jul 29 02:55 llave_prueba2.pub
-rw------- 1 root root 1766 Jul 29 02:56 llave_prueba3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  402 Jul 29 02:56 llave_prueba3.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  402 Jul 29 02:53 llave_prueba.pub
```

Y añado la información de autenticación de las primeras 2 usando

```
$ ssh-add llave_prueba llave_prueba2  # En este caso estoy dentro de la carpeta .ssh
Enter passphrase for llave_prueba:
Identity added: llave_prueba (llave_prueba)
Enter passphrase for llave_prueba2:
Identity added: llave_prueba2 (llave_prueba2)
```

Y ahora puedo listar las llaves de las que tengo registrada la información de autenticación con `ssh-add -l`

```
$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:x865ys5LAy8XSopI47DBm/AHRgisUxlXHfBHFEc2IFk llave_prueba (RSA)
2048 SHA256:lzNtSgyRBWZQBnWUULTaHuYcjagRJHiji9RDDu+mIAo llave_prueba2 (RSA)
```

La información de esas llaves se encuentran en la sesión del agente en el usuario que las ejecutó. Y ahí radica tu problema. Cuando ejecutas `sudo`, esa sesión no tiene el agente de autenticación y por eso te pide el passphrase de nuevo.

Quizás lo más adecuado es que copies esas llaves a un lugar propio y le cambies el propietario, de root a tu usuario no root, de esas llaves para que no tengas que usar `sudo ssh -i`. Otra opción es que hagas todo como superusuario, es decir, primero ejecutas `sudo su` y ya después puedes hacer uso de `ssh -i ...` sin necesidad de anteponer `sudo`.

Ahora, si por algún motivo extremo o neurótico deseas que todo se ejecute con `sudo`, se me ocurre una forma super sucia e insegura de hacerlo.

```
sudo bash -c 'eval $(ssh-agent)
pass=<escribe la passphrase>
expect << EOF
    spawn ssh-add /root/.ssh/llave_prueba
    expect "Enter passphrase"
    send "$pass\r"
  expect eof
EOF
ssh usuario@servidor -i /root/.ssh/llave_prueba'
```

Lo que hago aquí es utilizar `expect` y `spawn` para interactuar con el cuestionario de `ssh-add`.

Puedes hacer esto mismo dentro de un script que sea de la forma.

```
#!/bin/bash

eval $(ssh-agent)
pass=<passphrase sucia>
expect << EOF
    spawn ssh-add /root/.ssh/llave_prueba
    expect "Enter passphrase"
    send "$pass\r"
    expect eof
EOF
ssh usuario_sucio@servidor_sucio -i /root/.ssh/llave_prueba
```

Le das los permisos de ejecución con `chmod +x <programa>` y lo ejecutas con `sudo ./<programa>` y te conectarás a ese servidor sin necesidad de teclear la contraseña ya que la contraseña se encuentra en ese script, o la puedes leer de un archivo privado a través de ese script.